# Is my prove that $A \setminus B \subseteq \overline{B \setminus A}$ acceptable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

We should prove that $A \setminus B \subseteq \overline{B \setminus A}.$

Let $x \in A \setminus B.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
x \in A \setminus B & \implies x \in A \wedge x \notin B\\
& \implies x \in A\\
& \implies x \notin B \setminus A\\
& \implies x \in \overline{B \setminus A} \quad \quad \square
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: i dont know how :(

Comment: Please try to understand how I wrote your proof using mathjax so you can start to write yours in this way :) And yes, your proof is fine (as long as you know why all those implications work)

Answer (score 1):

I’m gonna just present a simple explanation of why these implications work, but the proof is fine!

Let $x \in A \setminus B.$ Then

$$\begin{align}
x \in A \setminus B & \implies x \in A \wedge x \notin B && \text{(by definition of “$\setminus$”)}\\
& \implies x \in A && \text{(Simplification)}\\
& \implies x \notin B \setminus A && \text{(by definition of “$\setminus$“)}\\
& \implies x \in \overline{B \setminus A} && \text{(definition of complement)}
\end{align}$$